# Xamarin.Forms Project Fails On Every Second Build After Clearing bin and obj

Tags: xamarin.forms

**Version Info:**

```
Xamarin Version:   16.8.000.260 (d16-8@fd405a2)

Xamarin.Android SDK Version:   11.1.0.17 (d16-8/c0e2b8e)

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK Version   14.6.0.15 (87a1b18d8)
```

Hi

**Description:**

Whenever I deploy my android project to my device to debug, I get the following error messages

> System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label
> syntax is incorrect.
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
> String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
> throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)    at
> System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
> recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.RemoveDirFixed.RunTask()
>
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
> path
> 'BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor.class'.
> at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath,
> Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound,
> WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)    at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String
> fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.RemoveDirFixed.RunTask(

I then delete the bin and obj folders in my pcl and platform project, run the project again and it builds and deploys to the device perfectly fine, if I attempt to run it again thereafter, I have to go through the same process again to get it running.

Comment: you clear the bin and obj folder in your project, it means that you delete these folders? If not, try to delete bin and obj folder from your project and try to compile again.

Comment: Sorry yes, it means I delete them, should've definitely been more clear about that.

Comment: do you reference any DLLs from the bin folder directly? check all reference path

Comment: I just checked, the only dll referenced from my bin folder is my PCL project's dll.

Comment: @CliftonSteenkamp you mean that you add PCL reference in your bin folder?

Comment: I have been having similar issues for several days, and today it has come back with the same message as you.  I had read previously that it could have something to do with the path being too long, but a key part of the message was not there this time (I don't remember exact details right now).  On a hunch, I closed the solution, renamed it, along with all projects, to something shorter, and restarted.  Then it worked.  So was it the renaming or restarting that fixed it for me?  Don't know, but maybe this will help you.

Comment: I searched through my browser history to find what I couldn't remember was in the error message I was getting last week.  It was MAX_PATH (failed to create ... due to MAX_PATH).  Funny thing is, this was an error from an unmodified project called DIContainerDemo downloaded from Microsoft with no changes.  After my previous comment, I moved DIContainerDemo to the root folder, and then it worked.  I had tried various fixes to work with long path names, but none had worked.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @MarcLevesque, I appreciate them, I'll give it a go when I get a chance and let you know how renaming my projects works out for me :)

Comment: @MarcLevesque Thank you soooo much! It actually worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by MarcLevesque in the comments below my question, I needed a shorter project path and this is what resolved the issue for me. In my case, I have all my xamarin projects located at C:\dev\Xamarin Projects, to shorten the path, I just changed that to C:\dev\Xamarin\ and that resolved the issue for me.

Thanks Again MarcLevesque!